# Custom properties or .ddl for JdbcRepository

Tags: quarkus, jberet

I'm using [quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet) integration and everything works fine.
Moving to a jdbc repository I need to add schema to JBeret tables but I haven't found a solution because native JBeret method (that is passing a properties object with specific keys to customize or load a custom DDL) seems to be not supported.
Any advice on how to bypass or solve this problem?

Comment: I see you have created an issue in the repository, that's the way to go. But if I were you, I would provide a bit more details about what you're trying to do in JBeret world and what the Quarkus integration is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Guillaume Smet I have integrated [issue](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet/issues/94) opened in [quarkus-jberet](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet) extension repository